# erroneous character spacing in pdf export when changing fontsize using matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, fonts, spacing

I use the Myriad Pro font in matplotlib by setting:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('font', **{'family' : 'sans-serif', 'sans-serif' : ['Myriad Pro']})
mpl.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
```

This worked fine for me using matplotlib 1.5.
I recently upgraded to matplotlib 2.0.0 and since then I have the following problem:
When changing the fontsize to smalles values (like fontsize = 2.0), 
all other fonts (axes labels and ticklabels) get affectted and 
the **inter characterspacing gets messed up**, so that all text elements overlap.

Below is a minimal example, which produces the bug for me:

```python
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

if __name__ == '__main__':

    f, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)

    # select custom font
    mpl.rc('font', **{'family' : 'sans-serif', 'sans-serif' : ['Myriad Pro']})
    mpl.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42

    # plot data
    xValues = [1.0, 2.0]
    yValues = [2.0, 3.0]
    ax1.plot(xValues, yValues)

    # add labels
    plt.title('my title', fontsize = 2.0)
    ax1.set_xlabel('x label')
    ax1.set_ylabel('y label')

    # save and show figure
    f.savefig('minimalExample.pdf')
```

[image]

I do not have this problem in the interactive version by calling
the

```
plt.show()
```

and I also do not see this behaviour if I save the output as a .png file instead of a .pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been already adressed here:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7937
and was apparently a problem with all type 42 pdf fonts.